# Cannot open videos in Opencv

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

I am trying to open .avi file in opencv. When I run the code I do not get any error but the video does not play. I searched around and I guess it requires ffmpeg to be installed. So I installed it using
    sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libavfilter-dev libswscale-dev 
It still does not work. Maybe the compiler needs to know where to find ffmpeg. I am using gcc compiler.
Thanks.

@Paul R: I have just copied the code from the Learning Opencv textbook, so wasn't including it. The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<highgui.h>
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
cvNamedWindow( "Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1] );
IplImage* frame;
while(1) {
    printf("Inside");
    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if( !frame ) break;
    cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );
    char c = cvWaitKey(33);
    if( c == 27 ) break;
}
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
```

}

@praks411:

```
printf("%s",argv[1]);
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1] );
if(!capture)
{   
        printf("failed\n");
    return -1; 
}
```

It prints the argument correctly and the capture fails.

Comment: You need to show the relevant part(s) of your code otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: @praks411: Are those instruction for using opencv with python? I am using opencv with C/C++

Comment: @praks411: I installed opencv again following your first link and it worked. thank you.

Comment: Ok, I've converted my comments into the answer can you up vote it or mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be the also the problem of your installation as you have installed ffmpeg after installing opencv, why don't you follow this link for proper installation on ubuntu.

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV
http://opencvstart.blogspot.it/2012/12/install-opencv-in-ubuntu-1204.html
```

I would also recommend to put check on cvCapture if you are able to create correct capture pointer and also try to print argv[1] to see if you are getting proper file name or not.